# Automatic column generation from levels based on conditional agggregation in groups using r

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, conditional-statements, tidyverse

To the below data frame, I am trying to create eight additional columns Last1Col7activ to Last10Col7inactive conditionally from FactorCol1:

```
library(tidyverse)
Data_Frame <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3"),
                         
                         Col2 = c("2011-03-11", "2014-08-21", "2016-01-17", "2017-06-30", "2018-07-11", "2018-11-28", "2019-09-04", "2020-02-29", "2020-07-12"),
                         
                         Col3 = c("2018-10-22", "2019-05-24", "2020-12-25", "2018-10-12", "2019-09-24", "2020-12-19", "2018-10-22", "2019-06-14", "2020-12-20"),
                         
                         Col4 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                         
                         Col5 = c(7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2),
                         
                         FactorCol1 = c("active", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "inactive"),
                         
                         FactorCol2 = c("Level2", "Level2", "Level3", "Level1", "Level3", "Level1", "Level2", "Level1", "Level3"))

Data_Frame$Col1 <- as.factor(Data_Frame$Col1)
Data_Frame$Col2 <- as.Date(Data_Frame$Col2)
Data_Frame$Col3 <- as.Date(Data_Frame$Col3)
Data_Frame$FactorCol1 <- as.factor(Data_Frame$FactorCol1)
Data_Frame$FactorCol2 <- as.factor(Data_Frame$FactorCol2)

Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% mutate(Col6 = lubridate::time_length(lubridate::interval(Col2, max(Col3)), "years"))
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Col7 = ifelse(Col6 <= 1, 1, ifelse(Col6 >1 & Col6 <=2, 2, ifelse(Col6 >2 & Col6 <=5, 5, ifelse(Col6 >5 & Col6 <=10, 10, 11)))))

Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Col8 = ifelse(FactorCol1 == 'active', 1, 0))
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% group_by(Col1) %>% dplyr::mutate(Col9 = ifelse(FactorCol1 == 'inactive', 1, 0))

Data_Frame <- as.data.frame(Data_Frame)

Data_Frame <- map_dfc(c(1, 2, 5, 10), ~ Data_Frame %>%
                          group_by(Col1) %>% 
                          transmute(!! sprintf("Last%dCol7active", .x) := sum(Col8[Col7 <= .x]),
                                    !! sprintf("Last%dCol7inactive", .x) := sum(Col9[Col7 <= .x])) %>% 
                          ungroup %>%
                          select(-Col1)) %>% 
bind_cols(Data_Frame, .)


  Col1       Col2       Col3 Col4 Col5 FactorCol1 FactorCol2      Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Last1Col7active Last1Col7inactive Last2Col7active
1   A1 2011-03-11 2018-10-22    4    7     active     Level2 9.7917808   10    1    0               0                 0               0
2   A1 2014-08-21 2019-05-24    2    6   inactive     Level2 6.3452055   10    0    1               0                 0               0
3   A1 2016-01-17 2020-12-25    2    3   inactive     Level3 4.9371585    5    0    1               0                 0               0
4   A2 2017-06-30 2018-10-12    1    1     active     Level1 3.4712329    5    1    0               0                 0               0
5   A2 2018-07-11 2019-09-24    4    3     active     Level3 2.4410959    5    1    0               0                 0               0
6   A2 2018-11-28 2020-12-19    4    2   inactive     Level1 2.0575342    5    0    1               0                 0               0
7   A3 2019-09-04 2018-10-22    4    5   inactive     Level2 1.2931507    2    0    1               1                 1               1
8   A3 2020-02-29 2019-06-14    4    1     active     Level1 0.8060109    1    1    0               1                 1               1
9   A3 2020-07-12 2020-12-20    4    2   inactive     Level3 0.4410959    1    0    1               1                 1               1
  Last2Col7inactive Last5Col7active Last5Col7inactive Last10Col7active Last10Col7inactive
1                 0               0                 1                1                  2
2                 0               0                 1                1                  2
3                 0               0                 1                1                  2
4                 0               2                 1                2                  1
5                 0               2                 1                2                  1
6                 0               2                 1                2                  1
7                 2               1                 2                1                  2
8                 2               1                 2                1                  2
9                 2               1                 2                1                  2
```

where:
Col6: time difference between max(Col3) and Col2 within each group

Col7: (<=) years for the values in Col6

Col8: active elements in FactorCol1 set as 1

Col9: inactive elements in FactorCol1 set as 1

Last1Col7active: Within each group (A1 to A3 in Col1), number of active elements in FactorCol1 that are <=1 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of active elements within the group

Last1Col7inactive: Within each group, number of inactive elements in FactorCol1 that are <=1 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of inactive elements within the group

Last5Col7active: Within each group (A1 to A3 in Col1), number of active elements in FactorCol1 that are <=5 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of active elements within the group

Last5Col7inactive: Within each group, number of inactive elements in FactorCol1 that are <=5 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of inactive elements within the group

Last10Col7active: Within each group (A1 to A3 in Col1), number of active elements in FactorCol1 that are <=10 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of active elements within the group

Last10Col7inactive: Within each group, number of inactive elements in FactorCol1 that are <=10 in Col7 and set that entire column to those number of inactive elements within the group

In an attempt to generate the columns automatically based on the levels from FactorCol1, the below code was used, however, the result shows that the values of ....Col7inactive values are always coerced into values of ...Col7active. What is going wrong?

```
map_dfc(c(1, 2, 5, 10), function(.x) map_dfc(levels(Data_Frame$FactorCol1), function(.y) Data_Frame %>%
                                               group_by(Col1) %>%
                                               transmute(!! sprintf("Last%dCol7%s", .x, .y) := sum(Col8[Col7 <= .x])
                                                         ,!! sprintf("Last%dCol7%s", .x, .y) := sum(Col9[Col7 <= .x])
                                                         )%>% 
                                               ungroup %>%
                                               select(-Col1))) %>% 
bind_cols(Data_Frame, .)


  Col1       Col2       Col3 Col4 Col5 FactorCol1 FactorCol2      Col6 Col7 Col8 Col9 Last1Col7active Last1Col7inactive Last2Col7active
1   A1 2011-03-11 2018-10-22    4    7     active     Level2 9.7917808   10    1    0               0                 0               0
2   A1 2014-08-21 2019-05-24    2    6   inactive     Level2 6.3452055   10    0    1               0                 0               0
3   A1 2016-01-17 2020-12-25    2    3   inactive     Level3 4.9371585    5    0    1               0                 0               0
4   A2 2017-06-30 2018-10-12    1    1     active     Level1 3.4712329    5    1    0               0                 0               0
5   A2 2018-07-11 2019-09-24    4    3     active     Level3 2.4410959    5    1    0               0                 0               0
6   A2 2018-11-28 2020-12-19    4    2   inactive     Level1 2.0575342    5    0    1               0                 0               0
7   A3 2019-09-04 2018-10-22    4    5   inactive     Level2 1.2931507    2    0    1               1                 1               2
8   A3 2020-02-29 2019-06-14    4    1     active     Level1 0.8060109    1    1    0               1                 1               2
9   A3 2020-07-12 2020-12-20    4    2   inactive     Level3 0.4410959    1    0    1               1                 1               2
  Last2Col7inactive Last5Col7active Last5Col7inactive Last10Col7active Last10Col7inactive
1                 0               1                 1                2                  2
2                 0               1                 1                2                  2
3                 0               1                 1                2                  2
4                 0               1                 1                1                  1
5                 0               1                 1                1                  1
6                 0               1                 1                1                  1
7                 2               2                 2                2                  2
8                 2               2                 2                2                  2
9                 2               2                 2                2                  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing I got the expected output with the code below:

```
library(tidyverse)

 # 1st step, make the changes to colum types and create Col7 tp 9
df <- df %>% 
  # Here I just make the changes to colum format as you did in your code ex
  mutate(
    across(.cols = any_of(c("Col1", "FactorCol1", "FactorCol2")), 
           .fns = as.factor),
    across(.cols = any_of(c("Col2", "Col3")),
           .fns = as.Date)
    
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Col1) %>% 
  mutate(
    Col6 = lubridate::time_length(lubridate::interval(Col2, max(Col3)), "years"),
    Col7 = ifelse(Col6 <= 1, 1, ifelse(Col6 >1 & Col6 <=2, 2, ifelse(Col6 >2 & Col6 <=5, 5, ifelse(Col6 >5 & Col6 <=10, 10, 11)))),
    Col8 = ifelse(FactorCol1 == 'active', 1, 0),
    Col9 = ifelse(FactorCol1 == 'inactive', 1, 0),
  )
# make the counts and merge them with initial df
df %>% 
  group_by(Col1, FactorCol1) %>% 
  # the trick is to use summarise to get the counts and then use pivot_wider and merge to "set that entire column to those number"
  summarise(
    Last1Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 1),
    Last5Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 5),
    Last10Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 10)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = FactorCol1, values_from = 3:last_col(), names_sep = "") %>% 
  right_join(df, ., by = "Col1")
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A2", "A3", "A3", "A3"),
                         
                         Col2 = c("2011-03-11", "2014-08-21", "2016-01-17", "2017-06-30", "2018-07-11", "2018-11-28", "2019-09-04", "2020-02-29", "2020-07-12"),
                         
                         Col3 = c("2018-10-22", "2019-05-24", "2020-12-25", "2018-10-12", "2019-09-24", "2020-12-19", "2018-10-22", "2019-06-14", "2020-12-20"),
                         
                         Col4 = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
                         
                         Col5 = c(7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2),
                         
                         FactorCol1 = c("active", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "active", "inactive", "inactive", "active", "inactive"),
                         
                         FactorCol2 = c("Level2", "Level2", "Level3", "Level1", "Level3", "Level1", "Level2", "Level1", "Level3"))
```

**Further explanations to answer "why setting `pivot_wider(values_from = 3:last_col())`?"**

```
df %>% group_by(Col1, FactorCol1) %>% summarise(
    Last1Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 1),
    Last5Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 5),
    Last10Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 10))
```

Gives you the following tibble:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   Col1 [3]
  Col1  FactorCol1 Last1Col7 Last5Col7 Last10Col7
  <fct> <fct>          <int>     <int>      <int>
1 A1    active             0         0          1
2 A1    inactive           0         1          2
3 A2    active             0         2          2
4 A2    inactive           0         1          1
5 A3    active             1         1          1
6 A3    inactive           1         2          2
```

You want the information of `FactorCol1` to be in wide format, with new columns containing values from the 3rd column (`Last1Col7`) to the last one. From `?pivot_wider`, we know that *"names_from, values_from    :  A pair of arguments describing which column (or columns) to get the name of the output column (names_from), and which column (or columns) to get the cell values from (values_from). If values_from contains multiple values, the value will be added to the front of the output column."*

Then, using `%>% pivot_wider(names_from = FactorCol1, values_from = 3:last_col(), names_sep = "")`, you get:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   Col1 [3]
  Col1  Last1Col7active Last1Col7inactive Last5Col7active Last5Col7inactive Last10Col7active Last10Col7inactive
  <fct>           <int>             <int>           <int>             <int>            <int>              <int>
1 A1                  0                 0               0                 1                1                  2
2 A2                  0                 0               2                 1                2                  1
3 A3                  1                 1               1                 2                1                  2
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain the role of values_from = 3:  (and why 3)?

Comment: I you run `df %>% 
  group_by(Col1, FactorCol1) %>% 
  # the trick is to use summarise to get the counts and then use pivot_wider and merge to "set that entire column to those number"
  summarise(
    Last1Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 1),
    Last5Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 5),
    Last10Col7 = sum(Col7 <= 10)
  )` you will see the state of the dataframe in your console. To get levels of `FactorCol1` as columns, you need to pivot is. And you want to keep values of the last 3 columns.

Comment: I hope it is clearer ^^ BTW, please see the updated answer. I though it was possible to do everything in one dplyr chain but I feel like it is needed to save an intermediate `df` to keep the columns you created in the final merge.

Comment: Thanks, I still didn't catch the point related to 3 (which last 3 columns are they).

Comment: @Ray answer edited with further explanations.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I understood it very well now.

Answer (score 0):

The following does the job, however it amounts to creating additional columns and removing them, but with other column names

```
ABC <- map_dfc(c(1, 2, 5, 10), function(.x) map_dfc(levels(Data_Frame$FactorCol1), function(.y) Data_Frame %>%
                                                             group_by(Col1) %>%
                                                             transmute(!! sprintf("Last%dCol7Col8%s", .x, .y) := sum(Col8[Col7 <= .x]),
                                                                       !! sprintf("Last%dCol7Col9%s", .x, .y) := sum(Col9[Col7 <= .x])
                                                             )%>% 
                                                             ungroup %>%
                                                             select(-Col1))) %>%
  bind_cols(Data_Frame, .)

# removing all columns that contain these names
Data_Frame <- Data_Frame %>% select(-contains(c("Col7Col9active", "Col7Col8inactive")))
```